# Problem building rosserial on Ubuntu MATE and ROS Kinetic on Raspberry 3 & Arduino

Tags: ros-kinetic, ubuntu, ubuntu-xenial

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hy there,

i am running this image on my Raspberry Pi3 (Ubuntu Mate 16.04 with preinstalled ROS Kinetic Full Desktop Package): http://www.german-robot.com/2016/05/26/raspberry-pi-sd-card-image/

I have troubles building rosserial in ROS Kinetic. I get following errors:

```
[ 95%] Building CXX object rosserial/rosserial_server/CMakeFiles/rosserial_server_socket_node.dir/src/socket_node.cpp.o
c++: internal compiler error: Killed (program cc1plus)
Please submit a full bug report,
with preprocessed source if appropriate.
See <file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-5/README.Bugs> for instructions.
rosserial/rosserial_server/CMakeFiles/rosserial_server_serial_node.dir/build.make:62: recipe for target 'rosserial/rosserial_server/CMakeFiles/rosserial_server_serial_node.dir/src/serial_node.cpp.o' failed
make[2]: *** [rosserial/rosserial_server/CMakeFiles/rosserial_server_serial_node.dir/src/serial_node.cpp.o] Error 4
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:2990: recipe for target 'rosserial/rosserial_server/CMakeFiles/rosserial_server_serial_node.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [rosserial/rosserial_server/CMakeFiles/rosserial_server_serial_node.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
[ 98%] Linking CXX executable /home/pi/catkin_ws/devel/lib/rosserial_server/udp_socket_node
[ 98%] Linking CXX executable /home/pi/catkin_ws/devel/lib/rosserial_server/socket_node
[ 98%] Built target rosserial_server_udp_socket_node
[ 98%] Built target rosserial_server_socket_node
Makefile:138: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
Invoking "make -j4 -l4" failed
```

I would be very glad if someone could help me :)

Thanks in advance,

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/259593/problem-building-rosserial-on-ubuntu-mate-and-ros-kinetic-on-raspberry-3-&-arduino/) by [mtROS](https://answers.ros.org/users/29774/mtros/) on ROS Answers with karma: 92 on 2017-04-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Ah, the internal compiler error. This is either a GCC bug or you just ran out of memory and the oom reaper took GCC from you. Do you have a spare flash drive? If so, you can format it to swap and use it to *hopefully* get through compilation.

Otherwise, this could actually be a GCC issue for arm. But that's rather unlikely, so please attempt the added swap solution before considering reporting to the GCC folks.

---

Originally posted by [allenh1](https://answers.ros.org/users/1086/allenh1/) with karma: 3055 on 2017-04-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mtROS](https://answers.ros.org/users/29774/mtros/) on 2017-04-19**:
Thank you very much! worked great!

I used  this instructions: https://askubuntu.com/questions/173676/how-to-make-a-usb-stick-swap-disk